# Create a WiFi hotspot in a Mac using a USB Wi-Fi dongle

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, hotspot

I have a MacBook Air. It has an inbuilt Wi-Fi. It is connected to an AP and has access to the internet. What I intend to achieve, is use my TP-Link USB Wi-Fi dongle on the Mac and make it a hotspot to share my native Wi-Fi device's connection.

So, the USB Wi-Fi dongle will act as an AP for external devices and it will share the internet connection of the Mac.

When I try doing it, my USB Wi-Fi dongle is being listed as 802.11n, So doesnt show Wi-Fi options for connection sharing.

Comment: While this should be technically possible, is it wise? If you can't connect other devices to a wireless AP you have access to with the laptop, you should ask yourself why. Are you trying to do something you're prohibited from doing? Are you trying to break the network owner's security paradigm?

Comment: Nopes, this is to enable communication between a hardware we provide and the MAC. The hardware we provide do not have option to configure VPN and hence the setup. The MAC would be connected to VPN and hence the corporate network and the hardware would be connected to the MAC through the configuration as stated in the question.

Comment: My end intention is to somehow enable communication between the hardware that supports only WiFi to a MAC without disconnecting the MAC's current WiFi connection. I suppose it is better that is asked as a separate question.

Comment: Honestly, I'd add all that detail the question.